# Script to clean disk on GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine, disk

I have an alert in Stackdriver for when disk usage is above 90%. Is it possible to create a script that cleans a specific folder whenever this alert is raised?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Not advisable to do so.

Is always a better idea to properly manage the data on your VM. You can use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to get rid of old logs.

If you really really want execute a script when an alert is triggered, you can use a [Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks) and tool like [Hookdoo](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) so when Stackdriver triggers an alert, it will call Hookdoo (installed) on your VM and can configure Hookdoo to delete some files on your VM.